# Something like overflow visible

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a grid with two rows, and I need to place some buttons in the second row that goes over the limit of the grid, like in this image:

[image: 5 Seconds to it - Game]

The problem is that the buttons are being cut. How can I do the same as the image?

Here is a sample of my current code:

```
<Grid Height="300" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/back_help.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Canvas Margin="30, 30, 30,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" x:Uid="MainPageHelpText" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/chalkboard-bold.ttf#Chalkboard" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" Width="338" Height="218" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform
                    X="2"
                    Y="2" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" x:Uid="MainPageHelpText" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/chalkboard-bold.ttf#Chalkboard" FontSize="26" Foreground="#af7f46" Width="340" Height="220" TextAlignment="Center">

                </TextBlock>
            </Canvas>

        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="Assets/ic_leaderboard.png" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0,-18, 0,0" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0, -30, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="Assets/ic_play.png" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0,-29, 0,0" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0, -30, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="Assets/ic_achievements.png" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0,-18, 0,0" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Why you want to exceed the limit of Grid? IMO define it little bigger, and position your elements as you wish.

Comment: I'm using an image as the grid background, that's why i can't just make the grid bigger.

Comment: And what's the background of those elements that should be little outside the grid? Ok, so maybe try to set another Grid above the one with background and put those buttons there.

Comment: I'll try it. I'm porting the game from the picture to WP8.1, that's why I need this "weird" positioning.

Comment: It worked partially. The button with an image is behind the grid background.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the order you put your elements - eg. first Grid with background, then buttons? Also is there any special purpose for this Canvas why not Grid?